# Ktor WebSockets serialization problems with Polymorphic serializer

Tags: kotlin, discord, ktor

I'm developing a kotlin wrapper for developing discord application and I'm using ktor client to handle it.

I'm stuck with a problem with serialization.

To handle discord websocket frame, I created a class `GatewayIntent` that contains this json

```json
{
  "op": 0,
  "d": {},
  "s": 42,
  "t": "GATEWAY_EVENT_NAME"
}
```

On this model, I'm using `op` as a classDicriminator and I have subClasses that correspond to each Event I must handle and where the `d` field is a different class.

On ktor websocket session, I create the polymorphic configuration

```kotlin
install(WebSockets) {
            contentConverter = KotlinxWebsocketSerializationConverter(Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                encodeDefaults = true
                serializersModule = SerializersModule {
                    polymorphic(GatewayIntent::class) {
                        subclass(HelloIntent::class)
                        subclass(HBackIntent::class)
                        subclass(IdentifyIntent::class)
                    }
                }
                classDiscriminator = "op"
            })
        }
```

It works fine to deserialize events but when I'm trying to serialize, the `op` field using as classDiscriminator is not set into the json string.

Comment: What type of the `op` property of your data class? What do you expect to be there after serialization?

Comment: op is a Int property and yes I would like to keep the information after serialization

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and found that it seems necessary to specify type info in order to properly use sendSerialized.

```kotlin
sendSerialized(HelloIntent(), typeInfo<GatewayIntent>())
```

or manual json to string.

```kotlin
send(Json.encodeToString(GatewayIntent.serializer(), HelloIntent()))
```